# WCF and System.Drawing.Color

Tags: wcf

**Thanks for the quick answers all. But I am looking for an answer and not a workoaround (serialize as string) as I want to know how to use other types from the framework**

I am fairly good at WCF but I think I am still at the beginners stage since I cannot serialize a System.Drawing.Color.

This is my Service Contract

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace wcfServer
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IColorService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Color DoWork();
    }
}
```

And here is an implementation

```
public class ColorService : IColorService
{
    public Color DoWork()
    {
        return Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

However, at the client WCF doesn't use a System.Drawing.Color but it generates it own color type (a struct) ?

The net result is that the color Yellow does not arrive at the client

I thought that this wasn't a problem since the .net Color type is marked with the serializable attribute

Kind Regards, Tom

Comment: Would it not be easier to send back a string representation of the colour you want? Then cast it to a colour on the client. Or is there a specific reason you want to send a Color object over WCF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, at the client WCF doesn't use a System.Drawing.Color but it generates it own color type (a struct)? [...] I thought that this wasn't a problem since the .net Color type is marked with the serializable attribute

I'm assuming you use basicHttp or wsHttp here. What I'm saying doesn't go for all bindings.

Communication between a WCF service and client has nothing to do with .NET. Keyword is interoperability. The client doesn't have to be written in .NET, it might very well be a PHP or Java or whatever kind of client.

WCF therefore uses SOAP to send and receive data, which all major programming languages implement. So to let a service and client exchange data, a format for that data has to be defined. You can't say "Hey, I'm gonna send a `System.Drawing.Color`", since that may very well not be a valid class or struct definition in the client's language.

So your service defines a WSDL, containing a schema definition, where the contents of the `Color` struct will be copied from `System.Drawing.Color`. It won't be linked to the .NET framework from the point it gets serialized and sent over the wire.

Answer (score 3):

Colors are usually a mess - there are so many of them. Just convert to color to a 32-bit ARGB structure (the Color class has a method that does this) and use that in your WCF interface. If you want to be extra careful, define your own struct with A, R, G and B (as bytes, WPF has them as doubles, but nobody really needs that), and decouple your service from any specific UI platform.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Don't serialize color, use the standard and simple argb value instead of a .NET type.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by using "KnownTypeAttribute" on a data contract. So you can try "ServiceKnownTypeAttribute" on a service contract like this :

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(System.Drawing.Color))]
public interface IColorService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Color DoWork();
}
```

This works fine assuming that the client code is also using .NET.
The strategy with "KnownType" worked well in my project http://www.nquotes.net/ and let me avoid additional serialization hassle. They should have included Color as one of the base types (as they do with Guid, for example, which is "known" automatically - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx ).